# Laravel order parent model by nested relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need some help with ordering in Laravel 10. I have a query and some joined relationships. My parent, paginated query is `Domain` and it joins `dns`, `blacklist` and `certificate`. All of these three are as hasOne relationship of a `Domain`.

I need to order the parent paginated domains model based on a field that the user chooses, in this case it's mapped via my `$sort` match case, as you see I might want to sort by the certificate's expiry date, which is in my `certificates` table, the following is my attempt at ordering my parent relationship:

```php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'perPage' => 'nullable|integer|in:10,25,50,100,250',
        'sort' => 'nullable|string|in:added,registered,expiry,domain,expiry_ssl,last_changed_dns,blacklist_count_most,blacklist_count_least',
        'search' => 'nullable|string|max:256',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return new ApiValidationErrorResponse($validator->messages());
    }

    $sort = match ($request->input('sort', 'added')) {
        'added' => ['domains.created_at', 'desc'],
        'registered' => ['domains.created_on', 'desc'],
        'expiry' => ['domains.expires_on', 'desc'],
        'domain' => ['domains.domain', 'asc'],
        'expiry_ssl' => ['certificates.expires_on', 'asc'],
        'last_changed_dns' => ['dns.has_changed', 'desc'],
        'blacklist_count_most' => ['blacklists.blacklist_count', 'desc'],
        'blacklist_count_least' => ['blacklists.blacklist_count', 'asc'],
        default => ['domains.created_at', 'desc']
    };

    $domains = Domain::query();
    $domains = $domains->where('user_id', Auth::id());

    if (str_starts_with($request->input('search'), 'tags:')) {
        $tags = explode(',', explode(':', $request->input('search'))[1]);
        $domains = $domains->withAnyTags($tags);
    }

    if ($request->input('search')) {
        $domains = $domains->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('domain', 'like', $request->input('search').'%')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'like', $request->input('search').'%')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'like', $request->input('search').'%');
        });
    }

    $domains = $domains->with([
        'certificate',
        'blacklist',
        'dns'
    ])->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1]);

    if ($request->boolean('just_list')) {
        $domains = $domains->get();
    } else {
        $domains = $domains->paginate($request->input('perPage', 10));
    }

    if (! $domains || count($domains) <= 0) {
        return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
            'message' => 'No domains found.',
        ], 404);
    }

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($domains);
}
```

Which returns:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'certificates.expires_on' in 'order clause'

How can I achieve said result?

#### UPDATE

```php
$domains = $domains->join('certificates', 'domains.id', '=', 'certificates.domain_id')
                    ->join('dns', 'domains.id', '=', 'dns.domain_id')
                    ->join('blacklists', 'domains.id', '=', 'blacklists.domain_id')
                    ->select('domains.*', 'certificates.is_valid')
                    ->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1]);
```

Attempting to do a `join` and getting my certificate's column data doesn't put it into the `certificate` object like using `with` would do. This is not the expected outcome.

[image]

Comment: If you want to `orderBy()` a column in another table, you have to use `->join()` syntax; `with()` performs subqueries for each of the relationships, and doesn't perform any kind of join, so `certificates.expires_on` is not available in your query.

Comment: Please could you provide an example based on my original post and attempt? I'd still like to retain the returned JSON structure, e.g: domain -> certificate. From what I gather, doing a join would actually then mean it effectively flattens the data which isn't great.

Comment: *"doing a join would actually then mean it effectively flattens the data"* - Not necessarily; if you omit including any columns from the joined table, then your results will still be the same (i.e. `->select('domains.*')`). I don't know your DB structure, the syntax is pretty straight-forward: `->join('certificates', ...)`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#joins

Comment: I've updated my post. When I use `join` and select my certificate's is_valid: `->select('domains.*', 'certificates.is_valid')` is does not put it into a `certificate` key like using `with` would. So the JSOn structure isn't correct.

Comment: I know, use both `join()` and `with()`; the `join()` is only the make `certificates. expires_on` available to `orderBy()`: `$domains = $domains->select('domains.*')->with(['certificate', 'blacklist', 'dns'])->join('certificates', 'domains.id', '=', 'certificates.domain_id')->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1]);`

Comment: Okay, but that's what I'm asking. It then doesn't match the JSON structure. are you suggesting to do `->with(['certificate', 'dns', 'blacklist'])->join()` etc? And that the join only affects the parent ordering?

Comment: That's correct; you use `->join()` **only** to make `certificates.expires_on` available to your `orderBy()` clause. `->with()` will still perform the additional subqueries to create the `certificate: { ... }` key.